# Two self maps $f,g:S^n\to S^n$ are homotopic if there is no $x\in S^n$ with $f(x)=-g(x)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

What I want to prove: Let $f,g:S^n\to S^n$ be continuous. If there is no point $x\in S^n$ with $f(x)=-g(x)$ then  $f\sim g$, then .

I am using this as a lemma to prove a slightly bigger result: Namely, For $n\in \mathbb{N}$, if $f:S^n\to S^n$ has no fixed points, then $f\sim T(x)=-x$ for all $x\in S^n$.
If you believe the above result, then it can be proven as follows:

Suppose there is no fixed point, and for the purposes of contradiction, $f\nsim T(x)$. Then $\exists x\in S^n$ such that $f(x)=-T(x)=x$ which means $x$ is a fixed point $\rightarrow \leftarrow$. Therefore, $f\sim T(x)$.

The problem is I am not even sure if the lemma is true. I believe it geometrically for $S^2$ but I don't know how to argue without using the language of analysis--I want to prove this without using a metric.

**My attempt**: I want to argue indirectly-- that is, suppose $f\sim g$ and for some $x\in S^n$, $f(x)=-g(x)$. In $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, if $f\sim g$, then for $t\in [0,1]$, $h(t)=tf(x)+(t-1)g(x)$. This is indeed a homotopty. If for some $x$, $f(x)=-g(x)$, then $-tg(x)+tg(x)-g(x)=-g(x)$ which is certianly not $g(x)$ at time $t$. Am I cheating when I use the linear homotopy as it goes outside of $S^n$?

Comment: What you want to prove is false. Consider constant maps with opposite values.

Comment: I see the problem. Any ideas how to salvage this? Maybe I insist that the maps are not constant? I know the second part is true ( if there is no fixed point, then $f\sim T(x)=-x$

Comment: As if the map is constant, there is a point that maps to itself. Namely, if $f(x)=c$ for all $c$, then$ f(c)=c$ is fixed and $c$ is a fixed point.

Comment: What you want to prove is that a map with no fixed points is homotopic to the antipodal map, right? This can be done by taking $$H(x,t)=\frac{f(x)t-(1-t)x}{|f(x)t-(1-t)x|}$$
This is well defined, since $f(x)t= (1-t)x$, taking norms gives $t=1/2$ and this can only happen if $x$ is a fixed point of $f$, of which there are none. This works if we replace $-x$ with $g(x)$ and assume $f(x)+g(x)$ vanishes nowhere.

Comment: You're not using the right lemma. What you want is the converse: no such point implies homotopic.

Comment: when you say converse, do you mean $f,g$ are homotopic unless $f(x)=-g(x)$ for some $x$?

Comment: Converse is : if no such point exists, then f and g are homotopic.